# Global WPF Toolkit Colorpicker StandardColors

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, color-picker, xceed

For a project i'm using the Xceed WPF Toolkit colorpicker to let the users select a color. This colorpicker is used in different pages and with our own custom colors. Therefore i want to create one global style in the `Application.xaml` and then use the colorpicker on the different pages, however i cannot find a properly working example of how to create a global style WITH an array of `StandardColors` other that creating it in code and copy/pasting the code onto the differente pages.

Hopefully someone could help me out with this.

The way i got it working now is:

Xaml on every page/usercontrol:

```
<xctk:ColorPicker
    Name="ClrPcker_Background"
    Grid.Row="4"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Width="300"
    Margin="3"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    SelectedColor="{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BrushToColor}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedColorChanged="ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged"
    ShowRecentColors="True" />
```

Code behind every page/usercontrol:

```
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(32, 32, 32), "DarkBackground"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(60, 60, 59), "DarkLightBackground"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(87, 87, 86), "LightGrayBackground"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(231, 76, 60), "RedLight"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(39, 174, 96), "GreenLight"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(52, 152, 219), "BlueLight"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(243, 156, 18), "OrangeLight"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(104, 34, 27), "RedDark"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(25, 110, 61), "GreenDark"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(22, 64, 92), "BlueDark"))
    CustomColorList.Add(New Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(116, 74, 9), "OrangeDark"))
```

Idealy i can also use our global UsedColors as ColorItems that are also added to the `Application.xaml`

```
        <!--  Background colors  -->
        <Color x:Key="clrDarkBackground">#202020</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrDarkLightBackground">#3C3C3B</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrLightGrayBackground">#575756</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbDarkBackground" Color="{StaticResource clrDarkBackground}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbDarkLightBackground" Color="{StaticResource clrDarkLightBackground}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbLightGrayBackground" Color="{StaticResource clrLightGrayBackground}" />

        <!--  Light Colors  -->
        <Color x:Key="clrRedLight">#E74C3C</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrGreenLight">#27AE60</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrBlueLight">#3498DB</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrOrangeLight">#F39C12</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbRedLight" Color="{StaticResource clrRedLight}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbGreenLight" Color="{StaticResource clrGreenLight}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbBlueLight" Color="{StaticResource clrBlueLight}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbOrangeLight" Color="{StaticResource clrOrangeLight}" />

        <!--  Dark Colors  -->
        <Color x:Key="clrRedDark">#68221B</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrGreenDark">#196E3D</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrBlueDark">#16405C</Color>
        <Color x:Key="clrOrangeDark">#744A09</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbRedDark" Color="{StaticResource clrRedDark}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbGreenDark" Color="{StaticResource clrGreenDark}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbBlueDark" Color="{StaticResource clrBlueDark}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="scbOrangeDark" Color="{StaticResource clrOrangeDark}" />
```

Comment: What is "CustomColorList"? You may want to consider creating a custom control that inherits from `ColorPicker`.

Comment: Thanks, ended up by creating a CustomControl that inherits ColorPicker, works like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating a custom control that inherits from `ColorPicker` instead of having to add items to a list of every view.

You can then for example add the colours to the control in its constructor.